# Munkaczer Tallis

Tags: minhag, chabad, tallit-gadol

I have been told by Chassidei Chabad that prior to their current pattern, the sixth Lubavitcher Rebbe wore a munkaczer tallis. What does this tallis look like?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65063

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://www.talitot.co.il/talitot/chabad/tlit-gdvl-hb-d-dgm-mvnqtw.html) that shows you the Munkaczer pattern.

Comment: So it's not really different from the modern Chabad tallis?

Comment: Here is the [regular](http://www.talitot.co.il/talitot/chabad/tlit-gdvl-hb-d-dgm-rgil.html) Chabad Talis

Comment: Gershon, I see Chabad tallitot often enough. I just have difficulty believing that the modern pattern isn't just a take-off of the Chabad tallis to capitalise on nostalgia.

Comment: The page linked to in the answer says it's the "Munkács-pattern Chabad _talis_". That doesn't mean it's the actual Munkács-pattern _talis_. Maybe it's just what Chabad folks like to call a Munkács-pattern _talis_ (but actual Munkács folks wear something else).

Comment: @msh210: Please post a better answer if you have one.