# What is the difference between a Rebbe Rashab Tallis and the regular chabad tallis?

Tags: minhag, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, tallit-gadol

What is the difference between a Rebbe Rashab Tallis and the regular chabad tallis Was this a specific thing just for his time or do chassidim still follow this today?

Is there a difference in tallis based on the time of year? Should my tallis during tishrei or just yom kippur have white stripes instead of black ones?

Does the tallis need to have the extra smaller knots on the sides?

Comment: What's a "Rabbe Rashab Tallis"? Do you have a picture or a description you can [edit] in?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64415

Comment: The second paragraph seems like a separate question from the one that's in the first and third paragraphs, unless I'm missing something. If I'm right, then I suggest you remove it from this question and ask it separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between the two is size. The Rashab Tallis is significantly wider. [Ben's Tallit shop](http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/rashab-tallit/) says it is the widest that he sells ("even wider than a size 90 Yemenite Tallit"). It is therefore significantly more expensive because it has the extra material. It is a recent thing to have such variations marketed at all.

There are slight variations in the patters of the black lines, but I haven't seen anyone make a serious suggestion of any significance to it.

There is no Chabad custom to wear a different patterned Tallis on different times of the year. You can see the Lubavitcher Rebbe's black stripped Tallis on Erev Yom Kippur [here](http://www.shturem.org/index.php?section=multimedia&id=1290).