# Why follow a rebbe's every custom?

Tags: minhag, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe

I'v noticed among some chassidim (Chabad in particular) that they will follow every minute practice attributed to a their rebbe, even to inconsequential ones. For example, I've noticed that most chassidim (such as Satmar) are not particular about following their rebbe's levush, tallis, et cetera to a tee (for example, I've noticed that chazzan Yaakov Yosef Stark, a Satmar, wears a fairly modern tallis [with regular black striping] and pants [rather than breeches and hose] which neither Satmar rebbe does). On the other hand, some (such as Chabad, Belz, and Skver) are very particular about seemingly inconsequential things, such as the pattern of striping on a tallis (Chabad or Belzer/Turkish) and the styles of hats specifically worn by their rebbeim.

This causes two questions:

- Why do some chassidim follow the every action or custom of their rebbe so exactly?
- Why do other chassidim not do so?

Comment: Do you know if Ya'akov Yosef Stark is a chazzan for a Satmar schul? Plus, I believe there are two Satmar rebbes now due to a dispute or something, so maybe they do follow the customs of their rebbes but that the two rebbes (who are brothers) have differing opinions and minhagim?

Comment: @EzraHoerster, Chazzan Stark is the chazzan at Orach Chaim, which is a YU-type MO schul. Both rebbeim wear the levush of their father and simpler tallitot (with silver atarot FWIW). My knowledge of Chazzan Stark's levush comes from davening in Orach Chaim when I'm in NYC.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt maybe he changes his clothes to be more "palatable" to his shul

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, then why does he wear a bekische and shtreimel instead of a more traditional chazzonish robe and kappel?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65086/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, how does that relate in any significant manner?

Comment: A story (joke) is that one day the rebbe decided to wear red suspenders,and all the Hassidim followed his minhag and wore red suspenders. After a week, someone asked the rebbe why he wore red suspenders. He answered, "To hold YOUR pants up!" The point is, many sects consider the rebbe almost on the level of G-d. Dress is probably the most important expression of self-identification as well as societal (outward) expression. Many of them feel that as in the "joke", the rebbe dictates all aspects of his followers behavior including dress which affects one's behavior. Thus, they follow the rebbe.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt It somewhat challenges the assumption that Chabadnikim follow everything their rebbes do.

Comment: The decision to follow the customs no matter what it is is the point, to manifest attachment. The content itself of the things is less relevant.

Comment: @DanF, I know that R' Yoel Teitelbaum was known to tell a chassidisch version of "sometimes a cigar is just a cigar"

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm aware, I've seen Chabadniks who don't wear their tallis folded under itself! However, Chabad does seem somewhat extreme in the respect of following rebbisch minhogim, even when they were not followed by most of the chassidim prior to the late 20th centuries (with the exception of four pairs of tefillin and saying Akdamus like most kehillot)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6146

Comment: Is there not an idea of maase Rav, if a Rav does something it is the correct way to do it, and that from the Rav's actions we learn more than from what he teaches?

Comment: @hazoriz no there is not.

Answer (score 2):

For chabad there are specifically some minhagim that the rebbe specifically made public and there are specific reasons for each one for us to follow (not saying I know all of them) and then there are things that the rebbe did himself which we dont need to do. There are those who make a point of copying those things as well as part of their hiskashrus because they personally feel doing so helps them with this. There are a few places that I've seen this discussed.

When looking at the directives from the rebbe we can see that coppying everything the rebbe did was unnecessary especially when it comes to mundane things. True hiskashrus comes from specifically doing those things the rebbe told his chassidim to do such as specific inyanim in learning, spreading chassidus, and all of the miftzoyim campaigns

Comment: Sorty for bad spelling. On my phone at the moment

Comment: What is "hiskashrus", why are people trying to do it, and how does doing things the rebbe said make it truer?

Comment: It means connection. How could you connect to someone through something not important to them? As to why is asking what is the chossid rebbe relationship. One perspective can been gathered by learning the maamar v'ateh tetzaveh.

Comment: please explain this sicha since I understand it as saying we should do everything the Rebbes do/did http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/10/24/197 please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: this isn't addressing the same thing. here this is talking about minhagim of the rebbeim and not inconsequential details